# Database structure assistance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design

I'm making an online exam system. In PHP I'm creating tables:

```
Table quiz info have this fields {
   id
   owner
   quiz_name
   question_qnty
}

Table questions have this fields{
   id
   quiz_id
   question_number
   question
}

Table answers have this fields{
   id   
   quiz_id  
   qeustion_number  
   answer   
   isright  
}
```

But I can't do that with Laravel. I want to let the user up to 12 questions and 4 answers.

Comment: What was the problem with doing it in Laravel?  It's hard to know how to help without seeing what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database can represent the *data,* and the physical relationships between the various sets of data ... e.g. linking a "question" record to the "quiz" that it belongs to, ensuring that there are no "orphan questions," and so on.

But the database cannot enforce "business rules," such as "up to X questions and Y answers."  Such concerns are strictly up to the you-programmed logic of your application.

At each and every appropriate time when the user tries to add another question or to add another answer, the logic of your application must consider and enforce the limit.